# Extend LinearLayout for App Widget

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-appwidget

I extended the LinearLayout class to create my own custom layout.

It works well when I put it on an Activity, but when I put in an appwidget I get:

02-11 13:16:36.906: W/AppWidgetHostView(6138): Error inflating AppWidget AppWidgetProviderInfo(provider=ComponentInfo{com/com.Provider}): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class com.CustomLinaerLayout

Is there a way to put a custom layout on an appwidget?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

taken from here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html

A RemoteViews object (and, consequently, an App Widget) can support the following layout classes:

```
FrameLayout
LinearLayout
RelativeLayout
```

And the following widget classes:

```
AnalogClock
Button
Chronometer
ImageButton
ImageView
ProgressBar
TextView
ViewFlipper
ListView
GridView
StackView
AdapterViewFlipper
```

**Descendants of these classes are not supported.**