# How to set time to Android AnalogClock in app widget?

Tags: android, layout, widget, components, android-appwidget

How to set custom time to Android `AnalogClock` placed in app widget?

As an alternative I was thinking to override default AnalogClock to set the time through codes. Or in other words, I would create my custom Clock which extends from default View or AnalogClock. Then put my custom Clock on widget layout UI.

Is this possible? I'm afraid we are limited on RemoteViews to have our own custom Component.

**UPDATE:**
This is error log I have following the solution given by vArDo at first.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Intro

It's not possible to include custom views in app widgets. [According to documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout) only small predefined subset of views can be used in layout. So, as you've mentioned, it's not possible to create your own `AnalogClock` view (as I've shown in my other answer) and include it in app widget.

However there are other means that can be used to create custom `AnalogClock` in app widget. In such implementation setting time directly in `AnalogClock` should not be a problem.

## Short answer

One of the ways to accomplish this is draw custom `AnalogClock` into `ImageView` (which is one of the allowed views in app widgets). Repeating `PendingIntent` is using `Service` to draw into `ImageView` every 60 seconds (via `RemoteViews`).

## Note on battery usage

Keep in mind that invoking `Service` action to update *app widget* via `RemoteViews` every 60 seconds is not so lightweight on battery. On *Jelly Bean* example implementation used 2% of battery during night (screen off, average network strength). However, I've been updating the screen every 15 seconds, which is not necessary when it comes to analog clocks. So a rough estimate would be that an app widget with one update per minute will consume about 0.5% of battery juice during night - this might be significant for your users.

## Solution details

### Changes drawing service

First of all you'll have to create `Service` that will draw into `ImageView` present in your view. Drawing code is pretty much taken from `AnalogClock` implementation and rearrange according to needs. First of all, there are no checks on whether time has changed - this is because `Service` will be invoked only when we decide too (e.g. every 60 seconds). Seconds change is that we create `Drawable`s from resources in the method.

Another change is that code draws analog clock into local `Bitmap` using `Canvas`:

```
    // Creating Bitmap and Canvas to which analog clock will be drawn.
    Bitmap appWidgetBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(availableWidth, availableHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(appWidgetBitmap);
```

Update is drawn into `ImageView` via `RemoteViews`. Changes are aggregated and then pushed into app widget on home screen - see [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html) for details). In our case there is only one change, and it is done through special method:

```
    remoteViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.imageView1, appWidgetBitmap);
```

Bare in mind that for code to work you have to declare what is available space for drawing your analog clock. Based on what is declare in your `widget_provider.xml`, you can determine the dimensions of `ImageView`. Note that you'll have to convert `dp` unit to `px` unit, before drawing:

```
    // You'll have to determine tour own dimensions of space to which analog clock is drawn.
    final int APP_WIDGET_WIDTH_DP = 210; // Taken from widget_provider.xml: android:minWidth="210dp"
    final int APP_WIDGET_HEIGHT_DP = 210; // Taken from widget_provider.xml: android:minHeight="210dp"

    final int availableWidth = (int) (TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, APP_WIDGET_WIDTH_DP, r.getDisplayMetrics()) + 0.5f);
    final int availableHeight = (int) (TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, APP_WIDGET_HEIGHT_DP, r.getDisplayMetrics()) + 0.5f);
```

I've pasted full code of `Service` subclass [here](http://pastebin.com/PFy4eDDK).

Also at the top you'll find the code that is responsible for setting time that will be displayed - modify as needed:

```
    mCalendar = new Time();

    // Line below sets time that will be displayed - modify if needed.
    mCalendar.setToNow();

    int hour = mCalendar.hour;
    int minute = mCalendar.minute;
    int second = mCalendar.second;

    mMinutes = minute + second / 60.0f;
    mHour = hour + mMinutes / 60.0f;
```

Also don't forget to declare this `Service` and app widget in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file, e.g.:

```
    <receiver 
        android:name="TimeSettableAnalogClockAppWidget"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"/>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_DISABLED"/>
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data 
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/widget_provider"/>            

    </receiver>
    <service android:name="TimeSettableAnalogClockService"/>
```

Most important info about using services to update app widget is described shortly in [this blog post](http://www.parallelrealities.co.uk/2011/09/using-alarmmanager-for-updating-android.html).

### Invoking drawing

Scheduling updates is done in `onUpdate()` method of your `AppWidgetProvider` subclass - the on that is declare in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file. We'll also need to remove `PendingIntent` when app widget is removed from home screen. This is done in overridden `onDisabled()` method. Remember to declare both actions that will call one of each methods: `APPWIDGET_UPDATE` and `APPWIDGET_DISABLED`. See excerpt from `AndroidManifest.xml` above.

```
package com.example.anlogclocksettimeexample;

import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class TimeSettableAnalogClockAppWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    private PendingIntent service = null;

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
//      super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
        final AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        final Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();
        time.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        time.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        time.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);

        final Intent intent = new Intent(context, TimeSettableAnalogClockService.class);

        if (service == null) {          
            service = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        }

        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, time.getTime().getTime(), 1000 * 60 /* ms */, service);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisabled(Context context) {
        final AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.cancel(service);
    }
}
```

Last line of `onUpdate()` method schedules a repeating event to happen every 60 seconds, with first update to happen right away.

### Drawing `AnalogClock` once only

Using above code the simplest way to invoke service only once is to schedule single event in time instead of repeating one. Simple replace `alarmManager.setRepeating()` call with following line:

```
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, time.getTime().getTime(), service);
```

### Results

Below is a screen shot with custom `AnalogClock` app widget that had time set only once (note difference between analog clock time and time shown in status bar):

[image]

Comment: Yes I like this answer. And I do not need to refresh the clock every minute. Because I want to show fixed time on this custom clock. I would also like to know how you managed to update the screen every 15 secs to save the battery life.

Comment: @Halim I've added details on solution. I've also describe how to modify code so that `Service` is invoke only once (this per your comment). However, I don't know what you mean talking about battery saving :) What I wanted to point out is that update every 15 seconds is more battery draining that update every 60 seconds which is pretty natural :) The only reason I wrote about 15 seconds interval is because this is what I had tried on my phone. Just wanted to show how does this impact battery life on phone.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to set time to something other than current time in `AnalogClock`. This widget is very encapsulated. You can easily change how it looks (in XML using attributes from [R.styleable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AnalogClock_dial), but there's no easy way to change its behavior.

I'd probably go with making copy of [AnalogClock.java](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/AnalogClock.java) (might be a good idea to put it in separate package, e.g. `com.example.widget`) and local copies of drawables [clock_dial](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/drawable-hdpi/clock_dial.png), [clock_hand_hour](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/drawable-hdpi/clock_hand_hour.png), [clock_hand_minute](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/drawable-hdpi/clock_hand_minute.png) (NOTE: to get best results you'll have to create local copies for all densities: [ldpi](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/master/core/res/res/drawable-ldpi), [mdpi](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/master/core/res/res/drawable-mdpi), [hdpi](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/master/core/res/res/drawable-hdpi) and [xhdpi](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/master/core/res/res/drawable-xhdpi)). With these in place and small changes to code, you'll be able to get the bahavior you want.

### Using custom drawables WITH attributes settable from XML layout

To be able to set `dial`, `hand_hour` and `hand_minute` drawables from XML layout files, you need to declare those attributes as styleable for your custom widget.

**NOTE:** In following example I've created `TimeSettableAnalogClock` and placed it in `com.example.widget` package.

Create `res/values/attrs.xml` file with following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="TimeSettableAnalogClock">        
        <attr name="dial" format="reference"/>
        <attr name="hand_hour" format="reference"/>
        <attr name="hand_minute" format="reference"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

`format=reference` means that values can only be references to other existing elements, e.g. drawables (`@drawable/some_custom_dial`).

Now custom attributes can be used in XML layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.example.widget"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.example.widget.TimeSettableAnalogClock
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        custom:dial="@drawable/some_custom_clock_dial"
        custom:hand_hour="@drawable/some_custom_clock_hand_hour"
        custom:hand_minute="@drawable/some_custom_clock_hand_minute"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Finally, you'll need to handle these custom attributes when `TimeSettableAnalogClock` object is created:

```
public TimeSettableAnalogClock(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
                   int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    Resources r = getContext().getResources();
    TypedArray a =
            context.obtainStyledAttributes(
                    attrs, R.styleable.TimeSettableAnalogClock, defStyle, 0);

    mDial = a.getDrawable(R.styleable.TimeSettableAnalogClock_dial);
    if (mDial == null) {
        mDial = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.clock_dial);
    }

    mHourHand = a.getDrawable(R.styleable.TimeSettableAnalogClock_hand_hour);
    if (mHourHand == null) {
        mHourHand = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.clock_hand_hour);
    }

    mMinuteHand = a.getDrawable(R.styleable.TimeSettableAnalogClock_hand_minute);
    if (mMinuteHand == null) {
        mMinuteHand = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.clock_hand_minute);
    }

    mCalendar = new Time();

    mDialWidth = mDial.getIntrinsicWidth();
    mDialHeight = mDial.getIntrinsicHeight();
}
```

Note, I've pretty much only removed `com.android.internal.` from reference to any *drawable* or *styleable*. The rest is the same as in [AnalogClock constructor](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/AnalogClock.java#L66).

### Using custom drawables WITHOUT attributes settable from XML layout

If you don't need your attributes to be settable through XML (e.g. all your analog clock will look the same in every place), you can simply the solution. You'll only need local copies of drawables (as mentioned at the beginning), no `attrs.xml` file is needed. Your constructor should look like this:

```
public TimeSettableAnalogClock(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
                   int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    Resources r = getContext().getResources();

    mDial = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.clock_dial);
    mHourHand = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.clock_hand_hour);
    mMinuteHand = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.clock_hand_minute);

    mCalendar = new Time();

    mDialWidth = mDial.getIntrinsicWidth();
    mDialHeight = mDial.getIntrinsicHeight();
}
```

As you can see, much shorter. The usage in XML layout is the same, but you won't need `xmlns:custom` part, and of course you can't set custom attributes anymore:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.example.widget.TimeSettableAnalogClock
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**I can update my answer further with more code of proposed solution, if you need more help on this one.**

Comment: I tried this solution. I copied AnalogClock source code from Android and put it on my own package. But I stuck on com.android.internal.R.styleable I don't know where to find this on Android source codes. Can you help?

Comment: @Halim The `com.android.internal.R.styleable` is used to handle attributes set in XML for `AnalogClock` (e.g. `dial` or `hand_hour`). If you want to handle such attributes in your custom analog clock widget, you'll have to declare them as styleable. I've updated my answer to show how to do this. I've also added part on how to simplify widget code if you don't need this feature (i.e. widget custom drawables set only in constructor).

Comment: thanks a lot for your codes above. However, I still have some questions. The new class TimeSettableAnalogClock does it extends from View or AnalogClock? If it extends from View, do we need to override method like onAttachedToWindow(), onDetachedFromWindow(), onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec), onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh),  onDraw(Canvas canvas), onTimeChanged(), etc?

Comment: And I'm still having problem on android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class my.package.com.TimeSettableAnalogClock Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:

Comment: @Halim Your `TimeSettableAnalogClock.java` should be **exact** copy of `AnalogClock.java`, except for changes mentioned in my answer. Which mneans **1.** Replace all *AnalogClock* strings with *TimeSettableAnalogClock* string. **2.** You need all three constructors (not only the one with three parameters) - this should fix your inflate error **3.** New class extends `View` **4.** You need to override all the methods you've mentioned (simply leave them as they are in `AnalogClock.java`).

Comment: Tried as you mentioned above but still having problem on on android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class my.package.com.TimeSettableAnalogClock Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException :( Yesterday I found http://www.kevindion.com/2011/01/custom-xml-attributes-for-android-widgets/ which has a good tutorial explaining how to call custom component on xml but today the site is down.

Comment: @Halim Can you put your whole `TimeSettableAnalogClock.java` somewhere, e.g. on [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com). Also how do you use this class? Please post your layout XML on pastebin. I have a working project created as I've explained above, so this must be some kind of small mistake in your code.

Comment: @Halim As, of the site you've mentioned - you can always use [Google cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3Awww.kevindion.com%2F2011%2F01%2Fcustom-xml-attributes-for-android-widgets%2F&sugexp=chrome,mod=4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) :)

Comment: http://pastebin.com/0bAGZdn2 http://pastebin.com/NfwURKK0 http://pastebin.com/0z5HAHq4 Can you please take a look? I'm desperate and cannot think clearly already. Perhaps you could help me point out something missing.

Comment: @Halim after quickview. In your layout XML file change line `xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/upper.duper.widget.alarmclock.full"` to `xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/upper.duper.widget.alarmclock.full"`. Note the change from **res** to **lib**. Check if this helps.

Comment: @Halim Another hint: uncomment lines 175-176 changing all attributes to method, e.g. `mRight` to `mRight()`, `mTop` to `mTop()`. Also why are lines 156-157 commented out?

Comment: namespace changes from res to lib does not impact anything. Still not working and the same error message. I cannot change mRight to mRight() instead I could do getRight(). Is that what you mean? And about line 156 - 157 commented out because the method resolveSizeAndState() is undefined. And on earlier version of AnalogClock they dont have these lines, so I think it should not a problem to comment it.

Comment: @Halim Yes, this is want I meant: `getRight()` and `getTop()`. Does `Eclipse` indicate any errors in `.xml` files? (Please `Clean` project and check for *red* indicator in `Package Explorer` view) Also checkout `Error Log` view in `Eclipse` - it sometimes shows additional info.

Comment: @Halim Also, I think that calling `setMeasuredDimension()` (lines 156-157) in `onMeasure()` is necessary (see docs for this method). What API version are you targeting? Lower than API 11? If so, please use [following lines](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3_r1/android/widget/AnalogClock.java/#149) - these use `resolveSize()` method.

Comment: No errors during clean and compile. Just runtime error. LogCat shows the above message error. Arrghh...haha I'm stressed.

Comment: I updated the code accordingly to the link you gave. I copy and paste CustomAlarmClock with AnalogClock replace the class name and made necessary adjustments. http://pastebin.com/0JcqL3Q1 And still giving me the error. I also tried solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376250/custom-fonts-and-xml-layouts-android and the same error happened. So I think something small is missing here. I don't know what.

Comment: Anything extra if this is to do on widget? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9239772/extend-linearlayout-for-app-widget says descendants is not supported

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/AEe1lu1M0Zs also says is not possible. So how you manage to do it? Can you share?

Comment: @Halim You never mentioned that you want to place your `AnalogClock` in **App** Widget. :) I thought that you just want to create your own `android.` **`widget`** `.AnalogClock`. So, I never tried placing it in app widget - I've placed customized `AnalogClock` in normal `Activity`. I'll try to do, what you want to achieve, later. Maybe, in fact, it's impossible (due to security reasons), as is mentioned in one of the links that you've provided.

Comment: Haha... so we had misunderstanding. Ok I will wait you try what I want to achieve as you said. Then you put it on another answer. I will accept your answer no matter the result is. Just to make this case closed.

Comment: @Halim I've been able to create custom `AnalogClock` app widget by drawing into `ImageView` every 60 seconds (`AlarmManager` used to schedule `PendingIntent`). See if this is acceptable solution for you - I'll add details if you're interested.

Comment: Yes absolutely. I'm interested to know how to draw hour and minute into ImageView. Could you share something? I would appreciate it.