# how to rotate an image in android widget using RemoteViews

Tags: android, android-studio, widget

From what i understand you cannot rotate an image in a widget using RemoteViews

Since they also depricated the analog clock widget, 
how do you do a simple analog clock Widgetusing your own images ?

I have everything set up in my widget,
I also have a timer that runs every minute,
I just need to rotate the minute dial and hour dial accordingly

been looking around and couldn't find an answer to this

how is that possible inside a Widget ?

i learn i can actually have 60 images for the minute dial + 60 images for the hour dial and then swap them progematicly.. but that's just an overkill...
isn't there a way to just achieve this simple thing that allot of people are doing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rotate an image and assign it to a ImageView. 
I leave a snippet in Kotlin that should help you.

```
val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.resources, R.drawable.minute_hand)
remoteViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.imageView, bitmap.rotated(angle))
```

where rotated function is :

```
fun Bitmap.rotated(angle: Float): Bitmap {
    val source = this
    val matrix = Matrix()
    matrix.postRotate(angle)
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.width, source.height, matrix, true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer to your question, but there are many implementation of analog clocks.
You can try [this](https://github.com/rosenpin/custom-analog-clock-view) whom looks very customisable

**Edit :**

I had never worked with widgets. It looks that you can't implement custom views inside anymore.

Check this answer :  [How to set time to Android AnalogClock in app widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11709934/how-to-set-time-to-android-analogclock-in-app-widget)

Comment: That could have been awsome if only this clock is for activity. I need one for a widget

Comment: that answer is using a depricated analog clock, i mentioned it in my post, my question is how to get around it since you cannot use it anymore